# How to bind multiples columns against a single row in gridview asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gridview

I am working on a bill customization project in which customer requirement is described below:

First there is an Invoice details table:
    e.g. (Table Structure and values)

```
Particulars  InvoiceNo  InvoiceDate InvoiceQty  UnitOfMeasurement Rate   Amount  Currency
Apple        I-90       2-12-2014   1000         Kg               8      8000     INR
```

It can contain multiple entries ..but the **InvoiceNo will be different**

Now another table contains an invoice's Damage Details (for insurance purposes)

e.g. (Invoice Damage Details Table):

```
Particular  InvoiceNo  invoiceqty  AffectedQty UOM  Rate Remarks
Apple       I-90        1000       100         Kg   8    Pressed so waste
Apple       I-90        1000       500         Kg   8    Smelled And waste
```

Now a Particular can contain different reasons for different quantity as mentioned above.

The last and final table contains all Information and the customer is demanding the following format to provide for easy access for their clients and users:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Particular | InvoiceNo | Date     | Qty |       Claimed        |       Assessed         |
           |           |          |     |------------------------------------------------
           |           |          |     |Qty  | Rate | Amount  | Qty  | Rate  | Amount  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                        |100  | 8    | 800     | 100  | 8     | 800       
Apple      | I-90      |2-12-2014 |1000 |500  | 8    | 4000    | 500  | 8     | 4000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 Total :           1000 | 600          4800    | 600          | 4800
```

Here  I want to show total Sum of Qty (total ) i.e. 1000 Kg  , Claimed Qty : 600 
    ClaimedAmount : 4800 .. Assessed Qty : 600 ..  Assessed Amount : 4800

There might be assessed quantity which can be edited by the owner, and amount and rate may also vary, but the main and important thing is how to show a row against multiple columns of Claimed And Assessed Description.

Code behind Sql Storage is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertTable] @claimID VARCHAR(25) = ''
,@Updateby VARCHAR(70) = ''
,@AffectedQty VARCHAR(30) = ''
,@myTableType MyTableType1 readonly
,@myInvoiceTable MyInvoiceTableNew readonly
AS
-- here MyTableType1 and MyInvoiceTableNew  are user defined data types 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DELETE
    FROM InvoiceDetail
    WHERE Claim_ID = @claimID

    INSERT INTO InvoiceDetail (
        Claim_ID
        ,Currency
        ,Particulars
        ,InvoiceNo
        ,InvoiceDate
        ,Invoice_Qty
        ,UOM
        ,Rate
        ,Amount
        ,UpdateBy
        ,UpdateDate
        ,STATUS
        )
    SELECT @claimID
        ,Currency
        ,Particulars
        ,InvoiceNo
        ,InvoiceDate
        ,Invoice_Qty
        ,UOM
        ,Rate
        ,Amount
        ,@Updateby
        ,convert(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 103)
        ,1
    FROM @myInvoiceTable

    DELETE
    FROM Invoice_Damage_Detail
    WHERE Claim_ID = @claimID

    INSERT INTO Invoice_Damage_Detail (
        Claim_ID
        ,Particulars
        ,InvoiceNo
        ,Invoice_Qty
        ,Affected_Qty
        ,UOM
        ,Rate
        ,Remarks
        ,UpdateBy
        ,UpdateDate
        ,STATUS
        )
    SELECT @claimID
        ,Particulars
        ,InvoiceNo
        ,Invoice_Qty
        ,Affected_Qty
        ,UOM
        ,Rate
        ,Remarks
        ,@Updateby
        ,convert(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 103)
        ,1
    FROM @myTableType

    DELETE
    FROM Invoice_Final_Assessment_Details
    WHERE ClaimID = @claimID

    INSERT INTO Invoice_Final_Assessment_Details (
        ClaimID
        ,Particular
        ,InvoiceNo
        ,InvoiceDate
        ,InvoiceQty
        ,ClaimedQty
        ,ClaimedRate
        ,ClaimedAmount
        ,ClaimedUOM
        ,AssessedQty
        ,AssessedRate
        ,AssessesAmount
        ,Createdate
        ,UpdateDate
        ,UpdatedBy
        ,IsDeleted
        )
    SELECT @claimID
        ,mt2.Particulars
        ,mt2.InvoiceNo
        ,mt2.InvoiceDate
        ,mt2.Invoice_Qty
        ,mt.Affected_Qty
        ,mt2.Rate
        ,(CONVERT(BIGINT, isnull(mt2.Invoice_Qty, 0)) * Convert(BIGINT, isnull(mt.Rate, 0))) AS ClaimedAmount
        ,mt2.UOM
        ,mt.Affected_Qty
        ,mt.Rate
        ,(CONVERT(BIGINT, isnull(mt.Affected_Qty, 0)) * Convert(BIGINT, isnull(mt.Rate, 0))) AS ClaimedAmount
        ,GETDATE()
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@Updateby
        ,0
    FROM @myTableType mt
    JOIN @myInvoiceTable mt2 ON 1 = 1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
END
```

And **now which join 1=1** i am applying in Database it repeats the number of line and invoice quantity and all amount gets doubled And USELESS.

Comment: Where is your C# code, What you have done so far???

Comment: What are you using to display the data?